# Detect if ReceivePort has handler prior to call

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I've got an isolate created using spawnFunction with an error handler provided and wrapping the send in a try/catch.

If I try to send to the replyTo and it doesn't have a receive registered then it (rightfully) throws a method not found exception but I can't figure out how to trap and handle it.

If you uncomment the recPort line it should all work fine.

```dart
echoIsolate() {
  port.receive((message, replyTo) {
    replyTo.send(message, port.toSendPort());
  });
}

bool errorHandler(IsolateUnhandledException ex) {
  print('Got error');
  return true;
}

run_tests() {
  test('bad rec', () {
    try {
    var recPort = new ReceivePort();
    //recPort.receive((message, replyTo) => print('Got echo: ${message}'));

    var isolatePort = spawnFunction(echoIsolate, errorHandler);

    isolatePort.send('message', recPort.toSendPort());
    } catch(ex) {
      print('Got exception');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (as of April 2013) there is no way to handle this error. (afaik)

Two improvements would solve the problem: 1) a way to set a global exception handler, or 2) an asynchronous try/catch.

Global exception handlers are already possible if the code runs in an isolate. One can pass an exception-handler as argument to `spawnFunction`. We are going to improve the API of isolates but currently that's the only way to catch uncaught exceptions.

We are thinking about asynchronous try/catch, but so far it's not more than ideas.

Edit: Also there is the question if this should even throw, buffer, or just discard the received value.

Comment: I would be totally happy with:
- a distinction between a one way and bi-directional port so I can check on client prior to replying (or turn down the request if I deem it important to talk back...)
- a constructor which allows optional reply for receivePort and defaults to a noop

Comment: Ohh... or the noop could, until overwritten, throw 'Unhandled reply in ReceivePort' or some such?  That way it's trappable (I think) and clearer what is happening...

Comment: And, finally, is there an existing bug for this that I can watch/put these thoughts into for better permanence?

Comment: The client can not know if the server has a handler. Isolates work asynchronously from each other.
I don't think there is a bug for your specific problem yet. Please file one.